# how to convert columns to numeric

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert all the columns of a data frame to numeric. 
MY data frame is formed from integer, numeric and factor variables.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

```
num_data <- lapply(data_training,  function(x) ifelse(is.integer(x), as.numeric(x), as.numeric(as.character(x))))

Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: How about `lapply(data_training, function(x) if(!is.numeric(x)) as.numeric(levels(x))[x] else x)`  You don't want `ifelse()` for this.  A regular `if()` statement will suffice

Comment: Do you want to convert the factor columns or leave the alone?

Comment: Integer **is** numeric, so I was guessing that you only wanted to convert the factors since you only have integer, numeric, and factor

Comment: The idea behind my question is that I'm trying to find if there is any correlation between variables...for that I was prompted that all my variables should be numeric.                                                                       @Richard: your way has NAs introduced by coercion in factor variable.

Comment: You probably have  `NA` in that column already, or some factor value that will not coerce to numeric.

Comment: @Richard > tail(data_training$classe)
[1] E E E E E E
Levels: A B C D E
> tail(num_data$classe)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA

Answer (score -1):

You are not creating any function. Try this:

```
num_data <- lapply(data_training,  f<- function(x) ifelse(is.integer(x), as.numeric(x), as.numeric(as.character(x))))
```